# Enable a disabled button after adding list item in dropdown

Tags: jquery, angularjs, button, dropdown

I am adding an item into dropdown through jquery and make it selected but disabled button could not get enabled after it in Angular.

```
<select ng-model="dropdown" name="DumyDDp" id="DumyDDp">
    <option value="0">-- Select Value --</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn" ng-disabled="(!dropdown)" >Save</button>

$(".OtherButton").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#DumyDDp').append($('<option>', {
        value: "1",
        text: "ABC"
    }));
    $("#DumyDDp").val("1");
});
```

Comment: Show what you have done ?

Comment: Can you past some sample code? Can't identify the problem from the given text.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Your question in its current form reads like "I couldn't be bothered; can someone do it for me?"

Comment: @JeevaJsb please take a look on it now.

Comment: Update the answer. Please check and tell me if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add item using jquery.

To disable and enable you are using the property `dropdown`.
The value of this can't be updated, since the object may be inherited somewhere.

Please use object throughout the application.
Like

```
obj.dropdown
```

For sample, I have added like this. you can change the `obj` name based on your need.

Go in an angular way. Use `data.model` to show the selected item.

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
                  <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
 </select>
 <button type="button" class="btn OtherButton"  ng-click="AddItem()">Add item</button>

//In Controller
        $scope.AddItem=function(){
             data.availableOptions.push({ id: "1",
                name: "ABC"});
        }
```

Comment: there is seprate button named "otherButton" and by clicking on it i am adding an item to dropdown and make that item selected in dropdown
 and then i want second button named "Save" that is already disabled by default to get enabled after adding new item in dropdown

Comment: Yes you can do. at first time have $scope.obj.dropdown=false. So save button will be disabled. After click on otherbutton, it will call AddItem method, there you can set as $scope.obj.dropdown=true, then this will enable the button